# Dockerized Flask app is not accessible in localhost

Tags: docker

I have been playing around with docker, celery, redis and Flask for the past 2-3 days, after successfully setting up a flask, celery and redis server I decided to go onto to the next point which dockerizing it. I have successfully created a docker image and a composer file which seem to work just fine when building. I am using a local redis server and I am able to access it by using `docker.for.mac.localhost` as the host name in order to access the redis server from inside the container, but, when I try to access the flask app while it's running from outside of the container it doesn't work.

Having done some research I have tried the following:

- Running with server host as `0.0.0.0`
- Exposing and using a different port other than `5000`

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000


CMD ["python3", "./app.py"]
```

And this is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "5000:5001"
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:5.0.5
    hostname: redis

  worker:
    build:
      context: ./api
    hostname: worker
    entrypoint: celery
    command: -A app.celery worker --loglevel=info
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I think your port mapping is backwards. If I'm not mistaken, the first is the external and second is the internal to map it to. If you're exposing 5000 for the app, you'd want to map 5001->5000 and connect on ipaddress:5001

Comment: Let me try this and I will update asap, thanks!

Comment: Seems like it worked!

Comment: Awesome! Added an actual answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your port mapping is backwards. It should be external to internal.

```
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
```